# Intellij: Adding 'Interface' to my context menu in the Project Pane

Tags: java, settings, intellij-idea

Currently in IntelliJ, if I right-click a package in the Project pane, I can see things such as:

```
new > Java class
new > File
new > Package
```

I want to add some new menu items in the 'new' context menu such as Interface and Enum.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I've been playing around in the **Settings > Menus and Toolbars** without any luck.

Edit: The funny thing is if I right click a package and choose **New > Edit File Templates...**, I can see the template for an Interface and in the description it actually says:

```
This is a built-in template used by IDEA each time you create a new Java interface, by selecting New | Interface from the popup menu in one of the project views.
```

Unless I need to look at a different pane other than **Project**, I can't seem to find any context menu that lets me choose **New > Interface** as suggested by the above description.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

New | Java Class, **Create New Class** dialog appears, in this dialog you can choose **Kind** between one of the following:

- Class
- Interface
- Enum
- Annotation

(tested with IDEA 9.0.3)

If you want Interface directly in the New list, then you have to add new template in Settings | File Templates, name it something like **Java Interface** and copy the contents of the **Interface** template into this one.

Comment: Thanks!  The second part of the response was exactly what I wanted.  After adding a NEW interface template to the 'file templates' section, it immediately appeared in my context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can create a shortcut to save some secs.

`Alt+Ctr+S` -> `Keymap` -> in search box type '`create new`' and select `Java class` and then assign any shortcut like `Ctrl+N`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's under the New Java Class menu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its available in Class menu : New--> Java class  --> Interface .

Answer (score 0):

create a package and then select create new class from that select interface and give a name.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvmrR.png)

then; you need to import the references files.

Answer (score 0):

It's under the New Java Class menu.new->java Class-{here select Interface option from dropdown.